# Arachnid fingers

Tags: biology, creature-design, anatomy

Is there a way arachnids legs could have finger like appendages at their ends in a way that makes sense for their structure and wouldn't look like a cheesy design?

This creature wouldn't be insect like in that it has an exoskeleton, as scaling up insects to the size I am after wouldn't work, so the creature would have a skeleton but would have a similar frame to a spider with the same forms of motion.

I already have an octopus like creature and due to its tentacles it can grab tools and interact with its environment to a degree I am after but I am struggling to see how this spider like creature can grab things without fingers.

So my question is what hand-like design would make sense for an arachnid and still allow it to move in a similar way?

Edit. As this creature is around 5 feet in length it doesn't have to crawl up sheer walls using the same hair like sticky method as spiders, it will just scuttle on the ground, roll using a pair of legs to propel and climb surfaces humans could, but with eight arms they could hang onto bumpy surfaces we couldn't.

Comment: ? Spiders belong to the subphylum [Chelicerata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelicerata), so named because its members have [chelicerae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelicerae). Some arthropods (including the scorpions, which in fact do belong to class Arachnida) have massive [chelae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chela_(organ)).

Comment: @AlexP pincers is an idea, I had originally thought their sharpness and clamping method means I cant do many tasks, but the idea can be built on.

Comment: Chelae are not necessarily sharp; they can be, but they do not have to be sharp.

Comment: Yeah I suppose it can work, Dr octopus used  three fingered grabbers on his tentacles arms that were similar to Chelae.

Comment: Intelligent spiders and octopus? Is someone a fan of Adrian Tchaikovsky? If you haven't, I highly recommend reading Children of Time and its sequel, Children of Ruin.

Comment: @Harabeck I haven't read them but I will check them out, thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps a modified form of the chelicerae, the mouth parts.  Once humans stopped walking on all fours, our fingers were free to become quite dextrous (course there was also the grabbing branches bit), so I think you are right in thinking that it would be rough for the alien to walk on them.

But, perhaps the mouth parts, which are used for manipulating food pulled up to them by the legs, could have further evolved to perform even more delicate detail work.

A fairly gross and alien idea to us, but I bet an elephant would find it quite elegant, given its dextrous "nose" and lips.

Comment: strange but interesting idea, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

While not a typical trait of arachnids, a way a creature like a spider could grab onto things would to have a type of [Raptorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raptorial), an appendage similar to a mantis' claws. It could use these as legs to climb or scuttle across the ground while still being able to grip things like handles, pry open certain objects, or grab onto pray. Since they would look like a normal leg on a arachnid it wouldn't look that strange, just like a pair of slightly thicker legs with more joints.

Comment: good idea, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Fingers are not present in most arachnids. But they are common in their distant relatives, [Crustaceans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crustacean).

Think of your creature as a crab, not a spider. It will walk on rear pairs on legs and use front legs for grabbing. Note that like with all exoskeleton-based arthropods, these fingers will be hard, not soft like in mammals.

Scorpions also have "fingers". They are much more closely related to spiders (although look less similar).

Comment: Scorpions **are** arachnids (= members of class [Arachnida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arachnid)) and they do have conspicuous chelae on their pedipalps.

Comment: @AlexP you are correct, scorpions are more closely related to spiders than crabs.

Comment: Scorpions are only very distantly related to crabs. Crabs (and crustaceans in general) are much more closely related to insects than to scorpions (and to arachnids in general).

Comment: @AlexP yes, that what I was saying too.

Answer (score 1):

Spiders, like many other limbed ecdysozoa (invertebrates that shed their cuticle), have claws at the end of their legs. In spiders, there are 2-3 of them. While they are not the most dextrous, it isn't ridiculous for them to be jointed in such a way that would allow them to be used as fingers